# Get dayof week from the date field Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

requirement is to get the day of the week from the date field, date field is in "MM/dd/yyyy" and need to be converted to "yyyy-MM-dd"

I think the date conversion can be done using Unix_Timestamp

but how do i **get day of the week** from the modified date field?

any help in this regard would be useful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change date format in hive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37558697/how-to-change-date-format-in-hive)

Answer (score 3):

Use the `extract(field FROM source)` to achieve the day of the week as of Hive 2.2.0.

Ex: `select extract(dayofweek from "2016-10-20 05:06:07") results in 5`.

Refer the date function manual for more info:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

**Note**: Conversion to the required format before extraction is needed.

Comment: Conversion to the required format was part of the question