# Hive-- change partition format

Tags: hive

I have some data that I'm currently partition by date, but hive's date format is "YYYY-MM-DD" and I need to convert that to the european format which is "DD/MM/YYYY"

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37558697/how-to-change-date-format-in-hive** have a look at it

Comment: saw this but I'm wondering if it's possible to do it at the partition level, or I have to insert the data into the table first and then do what you suggested?

Comment: also this works on `select` but I can't modify the columns themselves, which seems to be another problem hive has

Comment: also gave me this line `SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:22: Function unix_timestamp not registered`