# How would SQL treat this date format?

Tags: sql

I had a coworker run a data pull for me. The query was essentially

```
SELECT a, b, c 
FROM table
WHERE date >= 06/01/2018
```

The where clause being June 1, 2018. The query ran but the date filter was incorrect (not ‘2018-06-01’) How did the server interpret the date used?  Was any filtering applied?

Comment: what rbdms you are using?

Comment: It’s a Hive table, I am using Teradata client software

Comment: 06/01/2018 , to you, might look like "June 1, 2018" but to more people in the world it means "6th of Jan. 2018" or similar depending on spoken language (only ~10% of world's pop. uses mm/dd/yyyy). For 06/01/2018 to be correctly assessed as a the date you intend use a literal (i.e. within single quotes) and avoid the trap of using ambiguous date formats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specified exactly as you have shown it, without quotes, then it would probably have:

1) Calculated 6 divided by 1 divided by 2018 (resulting in an integer zero)

2) Converted the dates in your database to an int to match the compare data type, and done a compare.

I expect this returned all your rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this (datediff) function.

```
SELECT a, b, c 
FROM table
WHERE datediff(dateVar, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2018/06/01','yyyy/MM/dd'),'yyyy-MM-dd')) >= 0
```

1. `from_unixtime(,'yyyy-MM-dd')` converts string to a string of given format, e.g. '2018-06-01'

Alternatively, these are functions which can help:

1. `date_sub(,xxx)` subtracts xxx days from the string, and returns a new
   string in the same format.
2. `unix_timestamp(string date,string pattern)` converts a
   string of a given pattern to unix time stamp, ) if fail.

Reference: [How to change date format in hive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37558697/how-to-change-date-format-in-hive)

Comment: This is not answering the question

Answer (score 0):

This condition is:

```
WHERE date >= 06/01/2018
```

The last part is a numerical expression which I believe is interpreted as `(06 / 01) / 2018`.  Depending on the database, this would either be `0` or about `0.00297`, depending on whether your database does integer division.

Now the database has a bit of a conundrum.  It has a date on one side and a number on the other.  The rules of type conversion say to convert the date to a number.  Depending on the database, this could be an error or a valid number -- which would be larger than 0.

The correct way to express this is:

```
WHERE date >= '2018-06-01'
```

or:

```
WHERE date >= DATE '2018-06-01'
```