# Truncate date values in Hive

Tags: date, datetime, hive, timestamp, hiveql

I have the following value (format) for a column in a Hive table :

`2019-04-22 08:25:43.243754000000` `(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSSSSS)`

Is there a way to truncate this value as below ? :

`2019-04-22 08:25:43.243754` `(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS)`

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change date format in hive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37558697/how-to-change-date-format-in-hive)

Comment: @arghtype Using unix_timestamp and from_unixtime is an overkill in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove zeros at the end using regexp or substr(if you want fixed length).

Regexp example:

```
select regexp_replace('2019-04-22 08:25:43.243754000000','0*$','')
```

Result:

```
2019-04-22 08:25:43.243754
```

Using substr:

```
select substr('2019-04-22 08:25:43.243754000000',1,26)
```