# SQL Summing columns based on date key

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a dataset as given in the link, [DataSet](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=07d403b12c0c09825883f5ee8dcff292)

I want to segregate the column "order_item_unit_status" as separate column and bring respective transaction amount for the same. Desired output is given below.

[image]

Objective is to consolidate the txn_amt into respective categories and group them based on txn_date_key. (Basically pivoting based on order_item_unit_status column and bringing txn_amt respectively.)

I used the below code,

```
Select *, CASE WHEN order_item_unit_status ='DELIVERED'
THEN txn_amt ELSE 0 END as DELIVERED, 
CASE WHEN order_item_unit_status ='RETURNED'
THEN txn_amt ELSE 0 END as RETURNED
from sales
```

Got output as referred in the link [Output](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8a77ad6a2aaa3c6f4034b1df5be72c11)

The output is not grouping based on txn_date_key and multiple line items found. If i use  `GROUP BY txn_date_key` an error is thrown.

Also I was informed that server is supported by HiveSQL and does not support of using ":", date time, and temp tables can not be created. I'm currently stuck on how to go about given the constraints.

Help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All columns which are not aggregated and selected shold be in group by.

This query produces result you need:

```
Select txn_date_key, 
       sum(CASE WHEN order_item_unit_status ='DELIVERED' 
                THEN txn_amt ELSE 0 END)                  as DELIVERED, 
       sum(CASE WHEN order_item_unit_status ='RETURNED'
                THEN txn_amt ELSE 0 END)                  as RETURNED
from sales
group by txn_date_key
```

Result:

```
txn_date_key    delivered   returned
20190701           3200     0
20210631           0        3000
```

Comment: Hi @leftjoin I tried group by, but ended up getting an error. please find the link for error [Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2b315afdb7acf3888549a6de1879e388)

Comment: @Sid use query I posted: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b79d4b9d27f453d696d2c5a039f9db17. columns can be either in group by or aggregated.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use your columns in the `group by`:

**EDIT:** also `SUM()` added for the correct output...

```
Select *, 

SUM(CASE WHEN order_item_unit_status ='DELIVERED'
THEN txn_amt ELSE 0 END) as DELIVERED, 

SUM(CASE WHEN order_item_unit_status ='RETURNED'
THEN txn_amt ELSE 0 END) as RETURNED

from sales
group by txn_amt,txn_date_key,order_item_unit_status
```

In hivesql you can use `from_unixtime` command

[Unixtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37560612/10457877)